# Why delegates inside List are always equal when inserted through for-loop but not equal without loop

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, delegates

Let's look at the following code example. There is a List of delegates and later two instances are inserted inside that list sequentially.

```
class Client
{
    delegate void ActionListener(string message);
        
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<ActionListener> actionListenerList = new List<ActionListener>();

        actionListenerList.Add((message) => Console.WriteLine(message));
        actionListenerList.Add((message) => Console.WriteLine(message));

        if (actionListenerList[0].Equals(actionListenerList[1]))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Two Delegates are equal");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Two Delegates did not match");
        }
    }
}
```

> **Output:**
>
> Two Delegates did not match

Now, if we modify the code and add the delegates inside the list using for loop, then the output is completely different.

```
class Client
{
    delegate void ActionListener(string message);
        
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<ActionListener> actionListenerList = new List<ActionListener>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            actionListenerList.Add((message) => Console.WriteLine(message));
        }

        if (actionListenerList[0].Equals(actionListenerList[1]))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Two Delegates are equal");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Two Delegates did not match");
        }
    }
}
```

> **Output:**
>
> Two Delegates are equal

I guess, my question needs no further explanation - why is the difference produced after using for-loop?

Comment: I think this might actually be implementation-defined; Eric Lippert gives a similar example in [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2012/06/18/implementation-defined-behaviour/), for the "fourth factor" in his list.

Comment: Further question: how is the equality of delegates assessed anyway? by reference? if yes, then wouldn't the invokation of the first delegate in the loop also trigger the second delegate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the [language specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#evaluation-of-anonymous-function-conversions-to-delegate-types) *permits* both of the lambdas here to be converted to the same delegate instance:

```
actionListenerList.Add((message) => Console.WriteLine(message));
actionListenerList.Add((message) => Console.WriteLine(message));
```

> Conversions of semantically identical anonymous functions with the same (possibly empty) set of captured outer variable instances to the same delegate types are permitted (but not required) to return the same delegate instance.

So you might see two different delegate instances being created on your compiler, but on another compiler, the lambdas could be converted to the same delegate instance, as an optimization.

To make sure that you absolutely have different delegate instances (though I think this is rarely useful), you can capture a local variable inside the loop ([suggested by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70174544/why-delegates-inside-list-are-always-equal-when-inserted-through-for-loop-but-no/70174874?noredirect=1#comment124050204_70174631)). Now the lambdas don't have the "same set of captured local variables":

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    int x = 0;
    actionListenerList.Add(
        (message) => {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            _ = x;
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Your explanation makes sense, but I already tried with the example with `new` expression, and it didn't work. Could you make it working?

Comment: it seems that it depends more on the context. The local varible capture inside the loop results in 2 different instances:[fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/D8SKrf)

Comment: @Sweeper "I guess Jon Skeet's way is the only way then." I guess you can add this to the [facts list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts)

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know the spec allows combining anonymous functions

Answer (score 3):

```cs
actionListenerList.Add((message) => Console.WriteLine(message));
actionListenerList.Add((message) => Console.WriteLine(message));
```

In this version, there are two different functions. A lambda is just a one-line function, so if you have two of them then delegates to each of them will not be equal.

Effectively it's as if you wrote:

```cs
actionListenerList.Add(Lambda1);
actionListenerList.Add(Lambda2);

void Lambda1(string message)
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
}

void Lambda2(string message)
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
}
```

---

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    actionListenerList.Add((message) => Console.WriteLine(message));
}
```

In this version, there is only one function, so every delegate refers to the same function.

It's as if you wrote

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    actionListenerList.Add(Lambda1);
}

void Lambda1(string message)
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
}
```

Comment: Then, is it possible to create two different delegate instances using for loop anyways?

Comment: Not unless you declared it outside the loop. Why would you ever care, that is the question

Comment: If you introduce a local variable within the scope of the loop, and then capture that in the lambda expression, that will create multiple instances...

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks a lot. Your approach works perfectly. But, how does that work? Can you please explain?

Comment: @UmFraWJ1bCBJc2xhbQ: I don't have time to explain in detail right now, but fundamentally if there's a different context, the delegate *have* to be different (as they could produce different results).

Comment: @JonSkeet Pretty sure it's the same function being referenced, only the delegate is different because it references different captured variables (ie the internal `this` of the lambda which captures the variables is different, but the actual function being called remains the same). Whereas in the other version, a physically different function is being called. The effect is the same obviously: the delegates will not be equal

Comment: @Charlieface: The OP didn't ask how to make the lambda expressions refer to different methods - they asked how to get different delegates, so that's what I answered.